# Change image src onchange og Select

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the `src` of an image, to the value of the current-selected option in a `<select>`.
My function looks like this;

```
function changeImage() {
  var gameValue = document.getElementById("select-games").value;
  document.getElementById("select-game-picture").src = "img/game_" + gameValue + ".png";
}
```

I am not very experienced with JavaScript yet, so I do not have any clue what might be wrong here - I mixed some code from w3schools, and some here from Stackoverflow - changed the ID's and such, of course.

My image:

```
<img class="game-picture" alt="Logo of chosen game" id="select-game-picture" onchange="changeImage()">
```

Does anyone know what I've done wrong here...? :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: onchange event should be bound with select element not with image.

Comment: Thank you, @RajaprabhuAravindasamy ! That solved my problem, if you simply put this as an answer, I will mark it solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add [`onchange`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event to the [`select`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) element, not to the [`img`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) element.

Example:

```js
function changeImage() {
  var gameValue = document.getElementById("select-games").value;
  document.getElementById("select-game-picture").src = "img/game_" + gameValue + ".png";
}
```

```html
<select id="select-games" onchange="changeImage()">
  <option value="game1">Game 1</option>
  <option value="game2">Game 2</option>
  <option value="game3">Game 3</option>
  <option value="game4">Game 4</option>
</select>
<img class="game-picture" alt="Logo of chosen game" id="select-game-picture">
```